# C-compatible DLL in Fortran to call from Matlab

Tags: c, matlab, dll, fortran, intel-fortran

I want to create a C-compatible DLL in Fortran to later call it from Matlab.

I create* the .dll using the following fortran code in addnums.f90:

```
function addnums(val1, val2) bind(c, name='addnums')
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: addnums
use iso_c_binding, only: c_float
implicit none
real(c_float), intent(in) :: val1, val2
real(c_float) :: addnums
addnums = val1 + val2
end function
```

and the following header file addnums.h:

```
float addnums(float *val1, float *val2);
```

Then I run the following matlab script addnums_test.m:

```
loadlibrary('addnums.dll','addnums.h');
addnums(2, 2);
```

and get the following error:

```
Undefined function or variable 'addnums'.

Error in addnums_test (line 2)
addnums(2, 2);
```

Why is the function 'addnums' undefined? How can I fix this?

---

Update:

```
calllib('addnums.dll', 'addnums', 2, 2);
```

and

```
libfunctions(addnums);
```

yields the same error, so my guess is that the library itself is not compiled properly

---

*I use Visual Studio Community 2015 with Intel Fortran Compiler 15 and Matlab R2016b x64. When building the .dll I use x64 configuration, otherwise Matlab doesn't even load the library.

Comment: I don't know much about matlab but the information [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/calling-functions-in-shared-libraries.html) suggests you can use `libfunctions addnums.dll` to get information about what the library has provided, can you report what this returns? It also suggests you might need to do something like `calllib('addnums.dll','addnums',float1,float2)` to actually call your function.

Comment: Don't let me stop you, but you do know about `mex` files don't you ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Yes, I use `mex` files, but imho they look too cumbersome, and also should be in a fixed form format. Also I thought that creating C-compatible libraries would be a better solution for compatibility reasons.

Comment: @d_1999, calllib('addnums.dll','addnums',2,2) yields the same error.

Comment: Can you show how you compile the library?

Comment: @VladimirF what exactly do you mean? I have a Fortran Dynamic Library project in Visual Studio with a single `addnums.f90` file mentioned above and x64 configuration selected. Everything else is default. I just press a Build Solution button and thats it. `addnums_test.m` is in the same folder with `addnums.lib` and `addnums.h`.

Comment: Yes, I meant this kind of description. If you just press a default button or you specify some flags on the command line.

Comment: When using calllib you should not include the .dll extension.  Are the fortran runtime libraries, specific to the version of Intel Fortran that you are compiling with, on your PATH ahead of any other directories that may contain older versions of the runtime (which, very importantly, may include the MATLAB binary directory as MATLAB may install an older copy of the Fortran runtime DLL's).

Comment: @IanH Thank you, not including the .dll extension helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The valid syntax to call this library function from Matlab is:

```
calllib('addnums', 'addnums', 2, 2)
```

It is important to avoid the .dll extension in the library name.